# JVM - Implementation Questions

Tags: java

When we say there are different implementations of JVM , what the are different things that implementer must take care of? For eg: will javac compiler have to be coded? Is there a reference version available which can be customized and is this the route an  implementer typically takes?I assume Threading is something that can be implemented as per the implementer's choice , are there any other features that is dependent on JVM (for eg; works differently in different jvms). Will the compiled code be same irrespective of the JVM and does the difference typically arise only as part of runtime? Are there any other languages that provide different run-time implementations?

Comment: You'd do better here asking one question at a time.

Comment: Once you have reduced your question to a single, well-defined,  answerable question, general questions about programming languages are maybe a better fit on [*Programmers*](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Fundamentally, a JVM's "contract" is that it executes Java bytecode according to specification, and offers a few external interfaces (JNI and JNA). Thus, an existing `javac` can be reused. The reference JVM is Oracle's, and its sources are available; There's also the OpenJDK version, an IBM implementation, a Jikes RVM and others, although as far as I know none of these are forks of each other. Garbage collection is a feature that can be implemented differently, as well as the bytecode-to-machine-code translator and optimizer. In general, neither the bytecode nor the machine code will be alike.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist "Neither the bytecode nor the machine code will be alike"? The bytecode is defined by the JVM specification.

Comment: @EJP Of course; But I speak of the result of compiling Java source to Java bytecode, and there is no reason why one implementation of `javac` should give the same thing as another.

Comment: Thanks , I will refine this and post it in Programmers. @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist - Thank you very much for your response. Your response helped in clearing up most of my questions around this. Appreciate your help.